# How to generate Linear separable dataset by using sklearn.datasets.make_classification?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dataset

I'm using `sklearn.datasets.make_classification` to generate a test dataset which should be linearly separable. The problem is that not each generated dataset is linearly separable. How to generate a linearly separable dataset by using `sklearn.datasets.make_classification`? My code is below:

```
samples = make_classification(
    n_samples=100, n_features=2, n_redundant=0,
    n_informative=1, n_clusters_per_class=1, flip_y=-1
)
```

Comment: you can make a model with no hidden layers (linear model) and check if loss is zero of the trained model, if so, a line seperates the two features absolutely..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "linear separable" option, but you can reject a dataset when it's not linearly separable, and generate another one. Like this:

```
separable = False
while not separable:
    samples = make_classification(n_samples=100, n_features=2, n_redundant=0, n_informative=1, n_clusters_per_class=1, flip_y=-1)
    red = samples[0][samples[1] == 0]
    blue = samples[0][samples[1] == 1]
    separable = any([red[:, k].max() < blue[:, k].min() or red[:, k].min() > blue[:, k].max() for k in range(2)])
plt.plot(red[:, 0], red[:, 1], 'r.')
plt.plot(blue[:, 0], blue[:, 1], 'b.')
plt.show()
```

[image: sets]

This only tests for vertical or horizontal separation, but those are the ones you'd expect to happen with your setup anyway.

Also, increasing `class_sep` argument makes separation more likely to happen.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the question has been answered but there is also another interesting option `datasets.make_blobs`. Please see the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import datasets

X, y = datasets.make_blobs(n_samples=100, centers=2, n_features=2, center_box=(0, 10))
plt.plot(X[:, 0][y == 0], X[:, 1][y == 0], 'g^')
plt.plot(X[:, 0][y == 1], X[:, 1][y == 1], 'bs')
plt.show()
```